# Get Customer information from order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, customer-attribute

I want to retrieve customer information from sales order view observer in adminhtml section, currently i only know how to retrieve order in that observer like this:

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;
class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
  public function getCustomAttribute(){
    $order = $this->getParentBlock()->getOrder();

    return $order->getId();
  }
}
```

i need to retrieve the customer information from that order, if the order is from logged in customer

Comment: Did you try `$order->getCustomer()`?

Comment: You can directly access customer details like firstname,lastname,email from the order object . eg. $order->getCustomerEmail(),$order->getCustomerFirstname()

Comment: @Idham Most welcome

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Inside observer,**

```php
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 

$orderFromFront = $order->getRemoteIp();
$guestCustomer = $order->getCustomerIsGuest();
$groupId  = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
$firstname = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
$lastname = $order->getCustomerMiddlename();
$lastname = $order->getCustomerLastname();
$prefix = $order->getCustomerPrefix();
$suffix = $order->getCustomerSuffix();
$dob = $order->getCustomerDob();
$taxvat = $order->getCustomerTaxvat();
$gender = $order->getCustomerGender();
```

For **shipping address**,
`$order->getShippingAddress()->getData()`
And for **billing**,
`$order->getBillingAddress()->getData()`

You can get all type of customer data using **observer.**

Comment: is `$order->getCustomerIsGuest()`  to check if the order from customer logged in or not?

Comment: if customer is guest at that time its return 1 otherwise null

Comment: How do I get custom attribute of customer from order?

Comment: the guest placed an order, after that they have registered, then how do i map that  guest order  to them

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, $order->getShippingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId(); returning empty for me

Answer (score 3):

As per as,magento2 standard,you can inject Sales Collection Factory class,Then Filter that collection by Customer id.

```
protected $order;
public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        ) {
    $this->_order = $order;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


 public function getCustomAttribute(){
    $order = $this->getParentBlock()->getOrder();
   $orderdetails = $this->order->load( $order->getId());
    return  $orderdetails ->getCustomerId();
  }
```

or

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
$email = $order->getCustomerId();
```

But this is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

**Use repository**. With `$order` you can do

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')
    ->getById($order->getCustomerId());
```

`$customer` is an instance of `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer`, just call its get() methods to access customer properties.

Answer (score 1):

@Idham Choudry,

you can add below code in to your observer to get customer information.

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class yourobserver implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $customerSession;
protected $customerrepository;
protected $order;

public function __construct(
     Session $customerSession,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerrepository,
    Order $order
 )
{
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->customerrepository = $customerrepository; 
    $this->order = $order;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $orderIds = $event->getOrderIds();

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    $ordercoll = $this->order->loadByAttribute("entity_id",$orderIds[0]);

    $shippingdetails = $ordercoll->getShippingAddress()->getData();
    $magento_address_id = $ordercoll->getShippingAddress()->getId();
    $billingdetails = $ordercoll->getBillingAddress()->getData();
    $paymentdetails = $ordercoll->getPayment()->getData();
    $shipmentdetails = $ordercoll->getShippingmethod();
    $customerinfo = $this->customerSession->getData();
    $shipping_amount = $ordercoll->getShippingAmount();
    $discount_amount = $ordercoll->getDiscountAmount();
    $discount_description = $ordercoll->getDiscountDescription();
    $applied_rule_ids = $ordercoll->getAppliedRuleIds();

}

}
```

Comment: i want to retrieve customer information from order data not from session

Comment: Is the data you want on the order table or order_address table?

Comment: I have updated my coding to get order billing and shipping address information. you can get customer information.

Comment: How to get order item data?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should be able to give you customer information using order object -:

```
<?php
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class Order
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $_customerRepository;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    */
    public function getCustomerCustomAttributeValue($order){
        return $this->_customerRepository->getById($order->getCustomerId())
                                            ->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute_code')
                                            ->getValue();
    }
}
```