# How to get Customer Detail using Order id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer

Please Help me on this , i want get full customer data using order id.

1) I have a order id in my phtml file i want to get whole data using **block** class and phtml file.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181939/get-customer-information-from-order-magento-2?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @ChiragRajput

Answer (score 0):

You can get Customer id from order object as below.

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the customer id from order like below :

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
```

and then use customer id to fetch customer details using api factory like below :

```
<?php

namespace Yourcompany\Customer\Helper {

/**
 * Eav data helper
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterfaceFactory $customerRepositoryFactory) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepositoryFactory->create();
    }

    public function LoadCustomerById($customerId) {
         $cst = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
         return $cst;
    } 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code :

```
protected $salesOrderFactory;

protected $customerRepositoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $salesOrderFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterfaceFactory $customerRepositoryFactory
    ......
){
    ......
    $this->salesOrderFactory = $salesOrderFactory;
    $this->customerRepositoryFactory = customerRepositoryFactory;
    ......
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $salesData = $this->salesOrderFactory->create()->load($id);
    $customerId = $salesData->getCustomerId();
    $customerInstance = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    return $customerInstance;
}
```

***Note:*** Avoid to use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()